# jquery ui tooltip doent shows up html tags

Tags: html, jquery-ui, tooltip

Trying to append HTML tags within Jquery Ui Tooltip but it fails to show up the code as I need.

here I want to show this is tooltip

```
&lt;span&gt;Moew&lt;/span&gt;

$(function () {
      $.widget("ui.tooltip", $.ui.tooltip, {
          options: {
              content: function () {
                  return $(this).prop('title');
              }
          }
      });

      $(document).tooltip();
  });
```

Check my fiddle it does't show up the tag it directly render as html element.What is the mistake from me.

my output has to shown like `<span> Moew </span>` within the tooltips with html span tag.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Aa5nK/1900/)

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve here is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/Aa5nK/1901/

Comment: @Runcorn updated my question need to show up the html tag within the tooltip

Comment: Is this it : http://jsfiddle.net/Aa5nK/1908/